# My footer doesn't come out! "Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Icategory_Helper_Data' not found in /home/sample/public_html/app/Mage.php

Tags: footer

My site, when I click on product detail page,
my footer doesn't come out and instead, error msg comes out on the footer part

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Icategory_Helper_Data' not found in
>   /home/xxx/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 546

How Can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error, it is obvious that, you are using some custom extension in the footer and there is a helper call like this somewhere inside the footer section.

```
Mage::helper('icategory');
```

Since that extension is wrongly confgiured the helper section, Magento couldn't find the relevant helper corresponding to this call. So you should find the extension and add this inside it.

```
<config>
    <global>
        <helpers>
             <icategory>[Namepspace]_[Module]_Helper</icategory>
        </help
</config>
```

This is all we can say about this error right now. To get more info, you should put more details to the question

---

*[Namespace]_[Module]* should replace with the correct extension name

Comment: if the answer helped you, then feel free to accept this answer by put a tick which has at the left side of my answer